# ksh - exit script if last alphabet in variable is p

Tags: ksh

I'm writing a ksh script to refresh schema from prod to dev/test/qa environment. I would like to have disaster check in place, I'm asking user to input source and target database as well as schema names.  When the user accidentally enter prod database as target database name I would like the script to exit.  In our environment the production database name ends with p some times followed by 01, 02, 03 etc.

example names:

dbp
dbpp
dbpp01
dbpp02
cdp01
sedpbp
retpp01
PORP01
PORPP01

How can I check if the last alphabet not number of my variable string is p or P ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
SCHEMA=dbp
case $SCHEMA in
   *[pP] | *[pP]0[0-9] ) echo OK
   ;;
   * ) echo Error
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Sorry just needed a little tweek but answer is correct though

Answer (score 0):

I have added another check which checks if the source and target database names are same as well.

case "$tarSID" in
  *[pP] | *[pP]0[0-9] | "$tarSID"="SsrcSID")
     echo "Warning: Target Database Cannot be Prod or same as Prod"
     echo "Re-Enter Target Database Name
     ;;
  * ) 
  ;;

Thanks again Alvin